# Price Comparison Google sheet with Web sracping and conditions

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula, price

I just seem to be stuck with the IF’s and Importhtml/Xms etc.
 
My goal: I want a spreadsheet, where I put info like, EAN (GTIN-13), ASIN (Amazon Unique Article code). Now I want sheets to go to ebay.de & Amazon.de, take the price cheapest price from both sides - decides which price is cheaper. And subtracts 5% - this than is my finals price.

When the Article is neu or new others (Neu, Neu: Sonstige (siehe Artikelbeschreibung))

Eg. Cheapest prices:  eBay 40€ - Amazon 39€ // 39€<40€= 39€-5% = 37,05€ -> if the Article does not exist on one or the other, than it will only take the number, from the existing one -5%

The system however preferably, also should see, if shipping is included and add it to the price.

Eg. Cheapest prices: eBay 40€ +5€ shipping = 45€ - Amazon 50€ // 45€<50€= 45€-5% = 42,75€

> Price level:
> 0-100€ = -5% ///
> 100-1000€ = -10% ////
> 1000€ and more -15€

When the article is used, broken etc. (Gebraucht, Als Ersatzteil / defekt, Vom Verkäufer generalüberholt)

It only takes from ebay with the Used URL + Filter.

URLS:

eBay new: (this URL is with filter activation, for cheapest price wit shipping - Buy Now, EU Sellers, Accepting Returns & neu All these attributes are reflected in the URL.
https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=4548736101548&LH_PrefLoc=3&LH_BIN=1&LH_RPA=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_sop=15

eBay Used
https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=4548736101548&LH_PrefLoc=3&LH_BIN=1&LH_RPA=1&_sop=15&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=4

EAN can be automatically added from list:
New:

```
 ="https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw="&""&C2&""&"&LH_PrefLoc=3&LH_BIN=1&LH_RPA=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_sop=15"
```

Used:

```
="https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw="&""&C2&""&"&LH_PrefLoc=3&LH_BIN=1&LH_RPA=1&_sop=15&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=4"
```

Amazon
https://www.amazon.de/s?k=B07WD5978Q

```
="https://www.amazon.de/s?k="&""&B2
```

With

```
 =IMPORTXML(I2;"//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/a/span[1]/span[2]/span[1]")
```

I have tried to get the price from Amazon, but it doesn’t work.

From ebay I can get the price with:

```
=IMPORTXML(G2;"//*[@id='srp-river-results']/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span")
```

But not including the shipping cost in this example. Also I don't want the EUR to show but only plane number.

All other steps I need, like IF’s - Conditions (Used & New) etc. I have tried multiply option but completely failed.

You can find here an example spreadsheet I prepared but I just can't get further than this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DqnW4G_FQlnc8vVbz_q2wPako0VuExGcDkWCSACxXEk/edit#gid=705413209

I don't know if what I want is impossible to achieve. Maybe there is also another way than from what I was thinking. About any directions hints I would be glad since I only have a little more than basic knowledge.

Thank you
Lisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for amazon, you will need to use API: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

after that your formula will be:

```
=IF(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(G2; "//*[@id='srp-river-results']/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span"); "\d+(?:.\d+)?")+
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(G2; "//span[@class='s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost']"); 1); "\d+(?:.\d+)?"); 0)>

 formula(from_amazon)+formula(for_shipping_from_amazon); 
 (formula(from_amazon)+formula(for_shipping_from_amazon))-(formula(from_amazon)+formula(for_shipping_from_amazon))*5%; 

 (REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(G2; "//*[@id='srp-river-results']/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span"); "\d+(?:.\d+)?")+
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(G2; "//span[@class='s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost']"); 1); "\d+(?:.\d+)?"); 0))-(
 IMPORTXML(G2; "//*[@id='srp-river-results']/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span")+
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(G2; "//span[@class='s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost']"); 1); "\d+(?:.\d+)?"); 0))*5%)
```

Comment: @Guhlis I provided only logic. you need to substitute for formula(). unfortunately, without API, amazon cant be scrapped. a workaround would be to use some other website.

Comment: Hello
thank you for the prompt answer
this is not possible without API? And only use the URL's?
The code doesnt work now, but propably because of that.

I am trying to understand the code. 
Is there also included,
If new: use G2 & I2 (Or your that amazon formular you put)
If used only use H2

And the price levels.
0-100€ = -5% 
100-1000€ = -10%
1000€ and more -15€

Can I solve this with =lookup? 
I did a named range now for Price and percent, how do I integrate this code? (if this is the right one)
=LOOKUP(F2; price; percent)
Thank you for your help!